# How do I use conditional formatting to choose between columns for a datedif function?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I am trying to find the difference between two dates using this function `=DATEDIF(G2,K2,"D")`. I always want to find the difference between column `K` and either `G` or `H` depending on which one has a date. If a cell doesn't have a date it will have `-` in it.

How can I write an if function or filter to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try:

```
=datedif(max(G4:H4),K4,"D")
```

but may want to add some error trapping, in case K is less than G/H or they are both`-`.

I have absolutely no idea how or where Conditional formatting is involved in this.